# Multiple Goal Buttons in RVIZ?

Tags: navigation, rviz, visualization, turtlebot, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have to control more than one robot at a time. The robots are administered by a central ROS server and can be displayed and controlled using ROS RVIZ at the same time.
Every robot runs in a distinct name space such that same topics (like 'move_base/simple_goal') of different robots do not collide.

I was now looking for multiple *navigation goal* buttons in the tool panel of RVIZ, one for each robot. Currently I have to change the goal topic of the tool each time I intend to give the next robot a moving command. That is not very sophisticated and annoying.

Is there a *simple* way to have multiple buttons on the toolbar with the same functionality?
So far I found nothing that would help.

PS: I am not interested in running ROS cores on each robot and/or opening different instances of RVIZ, just in case someone is about to suggest anything like this ;)

Really appreciate any help and
thanks in advance.
J.Buesch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31559/multiple-goal-buttons-in-rviz?/) by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2012-04-10

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to hack rviz source and recompile it. Do as follows:

```
roscd rviz
cd src/rviz
```

Edit the file *visualization_manager.cpp* and go to line 215. You will see there:

```
createTool< InteractionTool >("Interact", "i" );
...
createTool< GoalTool >("2D Nav Goal", "g");
...
```

Copy the *GoalTool* line as many times as you need. Syntax:

```
createTool< TypeOfTheTool >("Label on the button", "shortcut_key");
```

Save and *rosmake rviz*. (If you've got precompiled packages remember to delete *ROS_NOBUILD* before *rosmake*.)

Now you free to add lines in rviz configuration files .vcg for each tool:

```
Tool\ Label\ on\ the\ buttonTopic=/robot_n/move_base_simple/goal
```

Have fun.

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on 2012-08-03**:
Would it really be that simple? :) Thanks for the accurate hints!

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-10-01**:
I was curious: is it possible to add another kind of button or shortcut key? example to stop refreshing the point cloud stream. Something close to RGBDSlam actually, but I want to show also the urdf model of my robot.

**Comment by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) on 2012-10-01**:
For new tools more hacking is required. You have to check out the source code of already existing tools in rviz/src/rviz/tools. All new tools must derive from Tool class (tools.h, tools.cpp). Once done, the above solution would be valid for new tools.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A clean solution would probably be to create an [Interactive Marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/interactive_markers) server that supplies this functionality (e.g. a huge flat box marker that you can click on).

This would also allow you to customize the functionality to your specific application.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on 2012-08-03**:
Yes, sounds like a reasonable approach.. More generic than hacking the sources.. When I placed the question my environment was not able to use interactive markers, but fortunately that has changed now.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-26**:
I think that this approach is better than the accepted answer as it can be used without hacking.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's an even simpler way than anyone else has described (except for @joq's answer) that doesn't require any hacking or coding whatsoever. You can add multiple instances of the same tool by using a custom (or modifying the default) `.rviz` configuration file.

Under the `Tools` section add:

```
- Class: rviz/SetGoal
  Topic: /name1/move_base_simple/goal
- Class: rviz/SetGoal
  Topic: /name2/move_base_simple/goal
```

where `name1` and `name2` are the names of your robots.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6